# is it possible to set the value of allocated memory with loops?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to manually set each individual character for my pointer instead of typing out the string/having another array and then simply copying the values.  This is homework, but I have it finished.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*function declarations */

void assignAlpha(char *pointer);
void assignNumeric(char *pointer);

int main()
{
    char  *cp;
    assignAlpha(cp);
    assignNumeric(cp);

}

void assignAlpha(char *pointer)
{
    /* allocate space for a-z character string */
    pointer = malloc(26*sizeof(char));

    char alphabet[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    strcpy(pointer, alphabet);

    /*print the values*/
    printf("%s\n", pointer);

    /*free the memory allocated */
    free(pointer);
}

void assignNumeric(char *pointer)
{
    /* allocate space for the 0-9 character string*/
    pointer = malloc(10*sizeof(char));

    /* input values */
    char alphaArray[10];
    int currentChar = 30;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
        alphaArray[i] = i + '0';
        currentChar++; 
    }
    /* copy string to pointer */
    strcpy(pointer, alphaArray);    
    /* print out the results */
    printf("%s\n", pointer);
    /* free the memory allocated */
    free(pointer);
}
```

What I have tried doing, but it seems to fail:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*function declarations */

void assignAlpha(char *pointer);
void assignNumeric(char *pointer);

int main()
{
    char  *cp;
    assignAlpha(cp);
    assignNumeric(cp);

}

void assignAlpha(char *pointer)
{
    /* allocate space for a-z character string */
    pointer = malloc(26*sizeof(char));

    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        pointer = i + 'a';
        pointer++;
    }

    /*print the values*/
    printf("%s\n", pointer);

    /*free the memory allocated */
    free(pointer);
}
```

I thought that if I go through each memmory address that I have allocated and set the value to the next character it would work, but I apparently was wrong.  Like I said this was a homework assignment, but I could hand in what I have that works and be fine. Any guidance on how to do this (if its possible) would be appericated!

Edit: I get the following error compiling "Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: How does it *seem to fail*? We need a specific problem description and question here. In what way does it *fail* exactly?

Comment: any one wanna explain the reason for 4 downvotes? I wasnt asking why my code isnt working, but a general implementation method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign to a pointer, you need to dereference it, like this:

```
*pointer = i + 'a';
```

Instead of:

```
pointer = i + 'a';
```

Otherwise, all you're doing is changing the value of the pointer itself, not the value of the memory location it is pointing to.

This explains your error: you're trying to assign the value `i + 'a'` (which is an integer) to a pointer type.

Another issue is that your `malloc` call needs to allocate **27** characters, not 26, because you also need a terminating `NUL` character.

Finally, when you go to print, your pointer has moved past the end of the string (because you've been incrementing it in your loop). The easiest way to fix this is to change `pointer = i + 'a';` to `pointer[i] = i + 'a';` and remove the `pointer++`

Comment: thanks for the input, however I tried that and the printf statement just gives me a new line.

Comment: @JeffreyQuinn: I missed a couple of other problems, please see my edit.

Comment: ahhh I see, didn't realize I was printing at the start but that makes sense. I am marking this as the answer since its working.